# Can We Use Same Certificate and Provisioning profile for Two Apps?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have Two Apps User App And Vendor App. For Push Notifications weather i have to make two provisioning profile and Certificate from same Account? Now My Application is not running on device. Please guide me how can i implement Push Notification for Both Apps.

Comment: for development & distribution you can use it, but production purpose we need the seperate the reason the Bundle ID is identify the particaular app in  device

Comment: you should have two certificate sets